# List of Interned String Reduce Memory Usage

Tags: c#, memory

With this following `interned` List, why wouldn't my List Memory Consumption is still quite high at 8MB?

I can see all the strings in the list have the same address.

Is this just how C# List works ?

[image: dotMemory]

```
int maxCount = 1_000_000;

var list1 = new List<string>(maxCount);

string val = "input1.country == \"india\" AND input1.loyaltyFactor <= 2 AND input1.totalPurchasesToDate >= 5000 AND input2.totalOrders > 2 AND input3.noOfVisitsPerMonth > 2";
for (var ix = 0; ix < maxCount; ix++)
{
    list1.Add(string.Intern(val));
}
var totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
Console.WriteLine(totalMemory/1024 + "KB");

Console.ReadKey();
Console.Write(list1[0]);
```

Comment: `string val = "literal"; String.IsInterned(val) == true`. `val` is assigned from a string literal. Loading a string constant from an assembly is already interned. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isinterned?view=net-8.0)

Comment: A `List<>` is backed by an array. The size of a pointer on a 64bit CPU is 8 bytes. So an array of `8 * 1_000_000` is clearly going to be ~8MB.

Comment: There's also no reason to be concerned with string interning here. `val` is always a reference to the same string and it's just added again and again. To better look at interning, set val to something that changes - like in the loop do `val = (ix % 10).ToString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list has 1,000,000 entries. Even if all the entries are the same, the *list* itself still needs space. And 8MB is exactly 1,000,000 times 8, as each entry in a list of a reference type such as string uses 8 bytes on a 64 bit CPU.

Comment: yes thanks, i realised that too, took a while